# How can i update postgis data from shp?

Tags: postgis, shapefile, update

Now,I know how to insert a shapefile to PostGIS by using `shp2pgsql.exe`.
If I have an updated shapefile and I only want to update the updated rows, how can I know the table being updated?

Comment: The normal usage of shp2pgsql is that you provide the table name that the parsed shape file should be sent to and then pipe this to psql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you're supplying the shapefile data in it's entirety back into Postgres when reissuing the shp2pgsql command, the only way would be to import to a temporary table and copy across the rows that are different to your original.  By the time you've had to compare every row, you might as well have replaced the whole thing with the temporary table anyway.  However, if you can somehow get a shapefile of just the changes, then you can just move over the rows that have been imported.

Answer (score 2):

Using shp2pgsql and pgsql on a Mac system but the principle should be the same as what follows here.

1. Load the modified shapefile into a temporary table;
2. Update the correct row of the original table with only the geometry from the modified shapefile.

---

Load the modified shapefile into PostGIS (I use the Bash pipe ('|') here to send the SQL from shp2pgsql directly to psql, not sure how you'd do it on Windows):

```
shp2pgsql updated.shp testing.temp2 | psql -d myDB
```

Now update the original table with psql:

```
pgsql -d myDB -c "UPDATE testing.temp2 SET geom = (SELECT geom FROM public.original WHERE gid=1) WHERE gid = 1"
```

---

In the example above:

- `public.original` is the table previously loaded;
- `updated.shp` is the modified shapefile;
- `testing.temp` is the staging data (a temporary table);
- the first row (`gid=1`) is the replacement data in this example but could be any row.